# Sitemesh 2.4.2 decorator issue with pattern

Tags: java, jsp, sitemesh

I am using sitemesh 2.4.2 and while it seems to be OK according to configuration when the decoration process begins for layout.jsp I get the following error:

Servlet failed with an Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream already closed

My decorator.xml is the following:

```
<decorators defaultdir="/decorators/templates/default">
<decorator name="layout" page="layout.jsp"><pattern>/*</pattern></decorator>
<decorator name="head" page="/decorators/common/head.jsp"/>
<decorator name="header" page="header.jsp"/>
<decorator name="body" page="body.jsp"/>
<decorator name="footer" page="footer.jsp"/>
<decorator name="content" page="content.jsp"/>
<decorator name="blockContent" page="blockContent.jsp"/>

<decorator name="simpleLayout" page="/decorators/common/layout_nomenu.jsp">
    <pattern>/login.jsp</pattern>
    <pattern>/error.jsp</pattern>
</decorator>
<decorator name="dialog" page="/decorators/common/dialog.jsp">
    <url-pattern>**/edit.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>**/view*.jsp</url-pattern>
</decorator>
<decorator name="simpleContent" page="/decorators/common/body_nomenu.jsp"/>
```

Login page is decorated correctly so I think the problem occurs when the layout decorator is applied.